# Is it possible for certains URLs to be accessed even if they are IP Blocked?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

Sorry if this might sound like a stupid question, but I just want to make sure. I have my `.htaccess` setup so that it blocks access from the outside when they try to access `example.com/phpmyadmin`. The only ones who have access to this are the IP address that I have set which is mine. I understand that people connected to the same network as me have access to this since we have the same public IP which is okay.

But is this method secure enough to really block users that are outside my IP? It's not just `phpmyadmin` but another directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

its a hard to answer question. 
the point here is the security involved. 
if you only have phpmyadmin and access to directories trough apache webserver, maybe the answer is almost a yes; but if you have a website on php, html, js or perl in the cgi-bin directories aside your http protected directories then you need extra considerations to afford security.

https://www.cvedetails.com/product/1341/?q=Phpmyadmin
you can check for phpmyadmin vulnerabilities maybe the version that ure using has a vulnerability and can bypass something, i dont know if a .httacces restricted folder yet.

maybe is a good idea to ask this on https://serverfault.com/